# How to create a variable in a if statement body in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a integer variable in a if statement body like this:

```
   if (a == 72){
        cout <<"You Are CORRECT1"<<endl;
        int aa = 1;
   }
   else{
        cout <<"No. The answer is "<<12*6<<endl;
        int aa = 2;
   }
```

When I compile this it says:
 `42 C:\Documents and Settings\Valued Customer\Desktop\C++\Variable.cpp` `aa` undeclared (first use this function)

Could you please help me.

Comment: This code does not give that Compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable before like so.

```
int aa;
if (a == 72)
   {
     cout <<"You Are CORRECT1"<<endl;
     aa = 1;
   }
   else{
    cout <<"No. The answer is "<<12*6<<endl;
    aa = 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable declaration is correct, the problem ís that the lifetime of your variable is only valid inside the block in which it was declared. Any attempts to use it outside this block is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional operator for this kind of situation:

```
int aa = a == 72 ? 1 : 2;
```

This allows you to initialize a variable based on a condition, something which cannot be done with an `if-else` statement. You will have to deal with writing to `stdout` separately though.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely telling you this when you're outside of your if/else statement.  In the example you give, you're creating local variables inside the scope of the `if` and the `else`.  They go out of scope and "cease to exist" after the `if` / `else` stuff.

Here's the way you should do it:

```
int aa = -1;
if (a = 72)
{
    cout << "You are CORRECT1" << endl;
    aa = 1;
}
else
{
    cout << "No.  The answer is " << 12 * 6 << endl;
    aa = 2;
}
cout << aa << endl;
```

By doing it this way, you declare the int outside of the scope of the `if/else` code block, so the variable continues to survive, and can be accessed outside of that code block.

Comment: Thanks for the help I am only a beginner to C++ and you did a good job explaining.